# crear una columna de contraseñas con pgcrypto

Tags: postgresql

quiero añadir una nueva columna a una tabla y que en ella se creen contraseñas en base al valor de otra columna de la misma tabla.

Quería saber si estoy haciendo lo correcto.

```
ALTER TABLE erp.tb_customer 
  ADD COLUMN password crypt(erp.tb_customer.cust_cif, gen_salt('md5'))
;
```

El error que me aparece es el siguiente:

```
ERROR:  no existe el tipo «crypt»
LINE 2:   ADD COLUMN password crypt(erp.tb_customer.cust_cif, gen_sa...
```

Leo que 'md5' no requiere instalación de la extensión pero igualmente la he hecho.

He probado también mediante el código siguiente, pero tampoco funciona

```
ALTER TABLE erp.tb_customer 
  ADD COLUMN password SELECT crypt(erp.tb_customer.cust_cif, gen_salt('md5'))
;
```

Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacer eso que planteas debes agregar la columna nueva con el tipo de datos `text`, pues eso es lo que retorna la funcion [crypt](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html#id-1.11.7.35.7.7) y luego hacer el update de esa columna, por ejemplo:

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;

CREATE TABLE tb (col1 text);
INSERT INTO tb VALUES ('1'),('2');
ALTER TABLE tb   ADD COLUMN password text default '';
UPDATE tb SET password = crypt(col1, gen_salt('md5'));
```

Nota: No puede hacer el ALTER TABLE con el resultado de crypt directamente pues no se puede establecer un valor `DEDFAULT` que dependa de otra columna de la tabla,obtendras un error similar a este:
`SQL Error [0A000]: ERROR: cannot use column reference in DEFAULT expression`

A no ser que saa un [GENERATED COLUMN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html), te recomiendo que le des una mirada